# Find an average age range over a span of ages

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find the most occurrences in a 10yr age range that can be Age 2 to 22, 15 to 25, 10 to 20, etc. in a table with `name` & `age`

I've created the SQL that returns the average age:

```
SELECT age, count(age)
FROM member
GROUP BY age
ORDER BY COUNT(age) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't believe you can do this with a single SQL call. You might want to do some research about stored procedures and Transact SQL (depending on what server you are using)

Comment: add your table and show some sample data

Comment: @PaulColdrey - Transact SQL is not going to be of much use since they have tagged the question `mysql`

Comment: Thanks @Tony - mea culpa. For MySQL this is a good place to start: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-compound-statements.html for the syntax of SPs

Answer (score 0):

Create another table `ages` to hold the age ranges you are interested in with a field for `age_lower`, `age_upper` and a display name `age_range` such as '2 to 22'

Join the tables with a `WHERE` clause that puts the age between the lower and upper ranges.

```
SELECT `age_range`, COUNT(`age`) AS age_count 
FROM `member` INNER JOIN `ages`
  ON age BETWEEN age_lower AND age_upper
GROUP BY age_range
ORDER BY COUNT(`age`) DESC, `age_range` ASC
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35884/12)

Comment: @user3014571 - I've corrected the SQL, which had syntax errors, and added a sample SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is still using predetermined age ranges, defined in the scheme. 1-10,11-20, etc. I need it to generate those ranges. Age 2 to 22, 15 to 25, 10 to 20, etc.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you need to find the smallest age (e.g. 2) and then generate ranges of 10 years from that stating point to group the ages? But the ranges you mention in your question seem to be random: "2 to 22, 15 to 25, 10 to 20". I find that a strange requirement for grouping ages for some sort of report. You would end up double counting some ages as your ranges overlap.

Answer (score 0):

This might solve the problem. The only thing I added was a table to hold values 1..x where x is your bucket count. The @T can easily be replaced with your MySQL table name. The results are all possible sets the age falls in, for each age. Then count of how many equal sets.

```
  --IGNORE BUILDING TEST DATA IN SQL SERVER
    DECLARE @T TABLE(member INT,age INT)
    DECLARE @X INT 
    SET @X=1 
    WHILE(@X<=100) BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @T SELECT  @X, CAST(RAND() * 100 AS INT)
        SET @X=@X+1
    END

    DECLARE @MinAge INT=1
    DECLARE @MaxAge INT=100

    --YOUR SET TABLE. TO MAKE LIFE EASY YOU NEED A TABLE OF 1..X 
    DECLARE @SET TABLE (Value INT) 
    DECLARE @SET_COUNT INT =10
    DECLARE @LOOP INT=1
    WHILE(@LOOP<=@SET_COUNT) BEGIN
        INSERT @SET SELECT @LOOP
        SET @LOOP=@LOOP+1
    END

    SELECT
        MinAge,
        MaxAge,
        SetCount=COUNT(CountFlag)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  
            MinAge=AgeMinusSetCount,
            MaxAge=AgePlusSetCount,
            CountFlag=1
        FROM
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT 
                 ThisAge,
                 AgeMinusSetCount=(AgeMinusSetCount-1) + Value,
                 AgePlusSetCount=CASE WHEN (AgeMinusSetCount-1) + Value + @SET_COUNT > @MaxAge THEN @MaxAge ELSE (AgeMinusSetCount-1) + Value + @SET_COUNT END
            FROM
            (
                SELECT 
                   ThisAge=age,
                   AgeMinusSetCount=CASE WHEN (age - @SET_COUNT) < @MinAge THEN @MinAge ELSE (age) - @SET_COUNT END
                FROM 
                   @T       
            )RANGES    
            LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Value FROM @SET) AS FanLeft ON 1=1
        )AS DETAIL
    )AS Summary
    GROUP BY
        MinAge,
        MaxAge
    ORDER BY
        COUNT(CountFlag) DESC
```